# JavaScript Toggle Button with Font Awesome Icon

Tags: javascript, button, toggle, font-awesome

I am new to the JavaScript world, and I'm attempting to learn how to use vanilla JS to program a button that will toggle its state between "play" and "pause." The issue I'm having is that I can verify in the console that my code is successfully toggling the class of the "i" tag, but the image doesn't seem to be updating.

Is this change not being reflected in the DOM tree somehow?

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="playBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="fas fa-play" id="transportIcon"></i>
</a>
```

JS

```
var getBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');
var getIcon = document.getElementById('transportIcon');

getBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (getIcon.className === 'fas fa-play') {
        getIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-pause');
    } else {
        getIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-play');
    }
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly for me... https://jsfiddle.net/gpxuo2vw/

Comment: The script is inserted into the page just before the closing </body> tag. That's the standard procedure, correct?

Comment: Yes, there must be something else wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested code example! However, I replaced my code with yours, and it's still not updating when I attempt to toggle the button in my local environment.

My project is on github, if you don't mind taking a look: [https://github.com/Audiosyncrasy/metronomejs](https://github.com/Audiosyncrasy/metronomejs)

Comment: I think Font Awesome is doing some things behind the scenes that is affecting my JS code. It's replacing the "i" tag with an "svg" tag and several different classes.

I think I might just need to use real images instead of FA. :-(

Comment: I use Font Awesome and have had no problems with it - I've certainly never seen it do anything like that.  Are you sure it's not something else doing that?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the debugger in Chrome, and version 5 of Font Awesome is changing things in such a way that my code doesn't work. Version 4 works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

there is working code example:

```js
var getBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');
var getIcon = document.getElementById('transportIcon');

getBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (getIcon.classList.contains('fa-play')) {
        getIcon.classList.remove('fa-play');
        getIcon.classList.add('fa-pause');
    } else {
        getIcon.classList.remove('fa-pause');
        getIcon.classList.add('fa-play');
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="playBtn" class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="fas fa-play" id="transportIcon"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the non-SVG version of Font Awesome (4.7.0). That way, my JavaScript isn't fighting with FA's JS that controls the SVG icons they use in version 5.